# Вопрос про коннекты в MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux

Допустим, у меня есть телеграмм бот, который использует на бд на моем пк.
После того, как я загружу его на VPS Linux сервер и туда установлю MySQL, после сделаю коннект, смогу ли я на своём пк дальше писать приложения, использующие бд, или нужно как-то разграничить?
Мне предложили использовать MUSCLE и установить его на сервер, но я этого не нашел.. Так что буду благодарен статьям по этой теме.

Comment: приложение писать сможете. Что и от чего вы собрались разграничивать?

Comment: Ну просто ничего такого, что два коннекта будет? Т.е один на моём пк, второй на линукс сервере. @ArchDemon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда Вы пишете приложение, использующее БД MySql - то это по определению распределенное сетевое приложение, использующее архитектуру клиент-сервер.

То есть, когда приложение делает запрос к базе-то приложению все равно, находится ли база на том же компьютере, или на другом континенте.

Поэтому никах проблем с тем, чтобы продолжить писать приложения, использующие БД на хостинге, нет, кроме... Кроме того, что понадобится установить connection с этим компьютером.

Тут вступает в силу некое правило, которое у MySql носит несколько параноидальный характер: создать коннекшн с локальной базой действительно проще, чем с удаленной.

Это не трудно сделать и с удаленной, просто больше телодвижений.

Я советую начать с того, чтобы установить MySql Workbench, и научиться им подключаться к нужным базам. как только в воркбенче получится - можно такой же коннекшн вписать в программу, и все будет работать!